# How to query firebase keys with a substring

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to query Firebase that contains an input. for example in the database structure below, I would like to query all nodes that contains "4140" 
so I use this code

[image]

```
  var catref = Cataloguedatabase.ref("/Listing Search/");


    return catref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => { 

    let snapdb = childSnapshot.val();
    let key = childSnapshot.key;
    //use ES6 includes function
    if(key.includes(schname)){  

    console.log(childSnapshot.val());
    var searchresults = childSnapshot.val();
    var container = document.getElementById('listing_gallery');
                      // container.innerHTML = '';

    var productCard = `
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="card" onclick="gotoproduct(this);" id="${key}">
                              `
         container.innerHTML += productCard;
                    }
                })
              })
```

This works but the problem is that it first query all the child and sort through the array.This is ok for node with few children but when it gets to thousands of children, it becomes impractical. is there a away i can only query key the contains the value in firebase and if not how else can i implement this?

Answer (score 8):

As Doug says, there is no way to query for values that **contain** a certain string. But you **can** query for keys that **start with** a certain substring:

```
return catref.orderByKey().startAt("4140-").endAt("4140-\uf8ff").once('value').then(function(snapshot){
```

This will just match the child nodes whose key starts with `4140-`.

Comment: is there any other way apart from firebase to accomplish this ?

Comment: Kato described a basic approach a while ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string, I recently described the "Firebase can do prefix matches, but not check 'contains' " here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48426478/209103. I'd nowadays consider using Algolia for a hosted search though.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is not possible with Firebase Realtime Database.  There are no substring queries.

If you're only interested in the first four characters for your query, what you can do is store that string as a child inside that node, then [orderByChild()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild) on that child to find only those items that begin with a certain four character sequence.

You can read more about ordering in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data).

Comment: is there any other way apart from firebase to accomplish this ?