# How to get all elements whose id contains a particular substring?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a chat with firebase realtime database.

Let's say user1 has uid1 and user2 has uid2, their chatId will be uid1_uid2 (ordered asc).
So the database chat/ looks like this:

```
chat {
  uid1_uid2: [message, message...],
  uid4_uid2:[message, message...],
  uid5_uid1:[message, message...],
  uid11_uid8:[message, message...]
}
```

Firebase rules are the following to allow only the interlocutors to have access to the conversation:

```
   "chat": {
          "$chatId": {
            ".write": "$chatId.contains(auth.uid)",
            ".read": "$chatId.contains(auth.uid)"
          }
          }
```

I want to get elements having uid1 in the chatId. So the expected return would be

```
{
  uid1_uid2: [message, message...],
  uid5_uid1:[message, message...]
}
```

Is there a way to get elements whose id contains a particular substring ? Something like...

```
databaseChat.child("contains uid1").on("value", snapshot => {

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  Realtime Database doesn't have substring queries.  The best you can do is find prefix strings in values.

[How to query firebase keys with a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896894/how-to-query-firebase-keys-with-a-substring)

Comment: Thank you ! databaseChat.orderByKey().endAt(uid1 + "\uf8ff").on() works as i expected. It seems to work like contains